# Line charts in Logarithmic Scale with Taipy

Tags: plot, scale, taipy

It seems that in Taipy the Line charts support the linear Scale on x, y axis.

Is there’s way to plot Logarithmic Scale?

Thanks

I know that there's a way to make Logarithmic Scale (saw it on another question on Stack) but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to plot a chart with a logarithm scale. Taipy is based on Plotly for charts. Layout parameters are accessible through the layout property. Other parameters of Plotly can be accessed through Taipy like for markers for example. Check the doc [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/chart/).

Here is a quick demo of how the x and y axes can be of the log scale. Here, the layout is being used to change the default behavior of the x and y-axis.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui

data = {"x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "y": [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

layout = {
  "xaxis": {
    "type": 'log',
    "autorange": True
  },
  "yaxis": {
    "type": 'log',
    "autorange": True
  }
}

Gui("<|{data}|chart|x=x|y=y|layout={layout}|>").run()
```

[image: Log Plot]

Other options of the same type can be found here: https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/